# Returned list is different from what it is inside function

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Here is my code:

```py
def solve(lists,sums,num_list_,num,a):
    if len(num_list_)==num:
        if add(lists,num_list_)==sums:
            print(num_list_)
            return a+[num_list_]
        return a
    num_list=copy.deepcopy(num_list_)
    for x in range(10):
        num_list[num]=x
        a=solve(lists,sums,num_list,num+1,a)
    return a

def add(lists,unkown_num_list):
    answer=0
    for x in lists:
        st=''
        for y in x:
            if isinstance(y,int):
                y=str(unkown_num_list[y])
            st+=y
        st=int(st)
        answer+=st
    return answer

unkown_num_list=[]
difference=[]
a=solve([[0], [1, 0], [2, 1, 0], [3, 2, 1, 0]],2000,[0, 0, 0, 0],0,[])
```

It printed:

```
[0, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 5, 1]
[5, 6, 4, 1]
[5, 6, 9, 0]
```

But for variable `a`, it is this:

`[[0, 0, 0, 9], [0, 0, 5, 9], [5, 6, 4, 9], [5, 6, 9, 9]]`

Why are these two different?

Is it because I used recursion? But other times, they don't have this kind of error.

I am using python3.6.1 and macOS High Sierra.

I am a beginner in Python, please point out any incorrect code.

Comment: Please explain the problem with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have a deepcopy in your `solve` function, in the `for` loop you still mutate the *same* `num_list` list after having added it to the result. So in cases where the `for` loop has more than one iteration, you'll get unexpected results.

One solution is to move the deepcopy *inside* the `for` loop:

```
def solve(lists,sums,num_list_,num,a):
    if len(num_list_)==num:
        if add(lists,num_list_)==sums:
            print(num_list_)
            return a+[num_list_]
        return a
    for x in range(10):
        num_list=copy.deepcopy(num_list_) # <----------
        num_list[num]=x
        a=solve(lists,sums,num_list,num+1,a)
    return a
```